# XML Row Layout is not working

Tags: xml, android-layout

Hey guys i have a questions i tried to set up a simple app that has some buttons and TextField in a Row Layout. I want every Button to fill 1/3 of the screen since there are three buttons.However it is just not working, it will show the first Button really big and the other ones small. Now another weird thing is that id i align the row on the very top it works.
The Code is bellow.
Thanks for your help,
Thorben

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffff804e">


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculater_information"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
         />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_column="0" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_column="0" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird things can happen when you combine layout_weight with layout_width of wrap_content.

Try instead setting your button widths to 0dp like so:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffff804e">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/calculater_information"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```